# How would I declare a global variable in Visual Basic?

Tags: vb.net

I want to create a variable that can be used across multiple forms.

It's going to be a temporary storage place for integers.

Comment: Ref. [Shared](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zc2b427x.aspx) - however, there are generally *cleaner* ways than to use static (Shared in VB) members and "global variables".

Comment: What would you recommend?

Comment: Depends on the particular problem, e.g. Is the data shared both ways? Is the value returned from dependent forms? Does the data represent shared application state or a per (controlling) form state? (For anything non-trivial, I recommend modeling the application state and *actions* outside of the form state itself; in this case an actual application controller/service can be shared and coordinate the different logic.)

Comment: It's taken from user input in one form. I want to use the value taken to store and retrieve data in a database afterwards.

Comment: In that case (and I'm assuming it's a modal dialog), I would have the parent form "accept" the values when the input form is closed. Here are [some general solutions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4787867/2864740); with either properties or events. Events are (much more) useful when not dealing with strict modal forms/input.

Comment: I agree with competent_tech. Add a Public variable to a module within in your project. This variable will be available to all your code (including the form you have). That's they way to make them global. Just set the user input to that variable and you can retrieve it at any time.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to do this in VB: a VB-specific way and a non-VB specific way (i.e. one that could also be implemented in C#.

The VB-specific way is to create a module and place the variable in the module:

```
Public Module GlobalVariables
   Public MyGlobalString As String
End Module
```

The non-VB-specific way is to create a class with shared properties:

```
Public Class GlobalVariables
  Public Shared Property MyGlobalString As String
End Class
```

The primary difference between the two approaches is how you access the global variables.

Assuming you are using the same namespace throughout, the VB-specific way allows you to access the variable without a class qualifier:

```
MyGlobalString = "Test"
```

For the non-VB-specific way, you must prefix the global variable with the class:

```
GlobalVariables.MyGlobalString = "Test"
```

Although it is more verbose, I strongly recommend the non-VB-specific way because if you ever want to transition your code or skillset to C#, the VB-specific way is not portable.

Answer (score 1):

IN VB6 just declare on top code

```
public GlobalVariable as string
```

then you can use GlobalVariable in any form as you like.

like

```
GlobalVariable = "house"
```

then you can use /call in other form

```
text1 = GlobalVariable
```

will show value "house"

Comment: or maybe you can use "form.tag" in form property as variable sender. to sent string within other form.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add it as `Public` to any `Module`

Example:

```
Module Module1
    'Global variables
    Public glbtxtTemplateName As String     'GLOBAL VARIABLE FOR TEMPLATE
End Module
```

VB loads the `Modals` first as a class and all `Public` items therein are shared directly. Think about it this way:

Lets say we have a `Module` called "MY_PROCESSES"

When you declare a `Sub` or a `Function` in "MY_PROCESSES" if you want it to be used outside of "MY_PROCESSES" you declare as `Public` like this:

```
Public Sub LOAD_TEMPLATE()
```

To get to LOAD_TEMPLATE you just call it in your code from anywhere:

```
LOAD_TEMPLATE()
```

So if I need to set or use the global variable that I made public in my module I just refer to it by name:

```
glbtxtTemplateName="TEMPLATE_NAME"

If glbtxtTemplateName = "" Then LOAD_TEMPLATE()
```

I do like building the class as above because you can reference it faster without remembering the variable but if you only need 1 or 2 global variables you can name them like we used to with Hungarian Notation style name.

This method is really quite simple and elegant. Old is new and New is Old.