# vb global variable to be accesses by different classes

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am new to VB and am working on an asp.net VB web application.

I have a partial class called s_new.aspx.vb which is the vb page behind the page s_new.aspx.

In this page there are a series of select dropdowns, which when selected lead to different options becoming available eg different select boxes appearing and or with different options.

One particular select box accesses a method in a different class (webcontrols).

My problem is that I need the web controls class to change its behavior based on a certain selection made in the s_new.aspx.vb page.

If I was using C# I would create a global variable and use that as a decision maker, but I cant seem to to this in VB.

below is a snippet of the code I am using:

```
Partial Class s_new

    Protected Sub fldSourceofFunds_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles fldSourceofFunds.SelectedIndexChanged
        Select Case fldSourceofFunds.SelectedIndex
            Case 1
               ####
            Case 2
               ###
            Case 3
               do something and set the variable
        End Select
    End Sub



Partial Class Webcontrols

    Private Sub ReloadChildren()
        If (variable from s_new has certain value) Then    
            ResetChildren()

            Select Case PaymentMethodValue.ToLower.Trim
                Case "payment via provider/platform"
                Case "payment direct from client"
                Case "payment via provider/platform and payment direct from client"
            End Select
        End if

    End Sub
End Class
```

This is an existing project and I need to minimize the changes I make to the project, eg I am not able to make large changes to the structure to accommodate this change. As I said above, this would be a simple solution in C# and I assume it is simple here to.

Comment: Answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22738243/how-would-i-declare-a-global-variable-in-visual-basic

Comment: It may be a "simple solution" in C# but it's almost certainly a *wrong* solution also. Global variables in an asp.net application will lose their value whenever the application pool is recycled *and* they're shared by all users of the web application. Almost always, neither of these are what you'd actually want.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Ok so I understand that using a global variable may be wrong, but I hope it is clear what I am trying to achieve, which I do not think is wrong. Do you have any advice on how I can achieve this?

Comment: I haven't read it thoroughly but [this codeproject article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/857879/How-to-share-data-among-different-web-pages-using) looks like it has the basics covered. There are trade-offs between different solutions (e.g. request vs session vs cookies) so it depends on *why* you wanted to share this data and within what scope. Information not in your question.