# SQL Result to Global Variable

Tags: vb.net, mdi

Within my MDIParent Me_Load I have an SQL query that returns user information based upon Windows ID. This works well, however I'd really like to move this logic out into perhaps a module and assign each value in the db to a global variable to be used elsewhere. I'd like to be able to access the contact_id in any child form of the parent MDI. I'm used to PHP where I'd just assign it to a session variable that I could reference anywhere.

This is my current SQL Code

```
            Dim sql_query As String

        Dim errorMessages As New StringBuilder()
        Dim cnn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("sql_connection_string").ConnectionString
        Dim adapter As SqlDataAdapter
        Dim ds As New DataTable()
        Dim User_ID As String
        Dim User_First_Name As String
        Dim User_Last_Name As String
        Dim User_Contact_CD As String
        Dim User_Login As String

        sql_query = "SELECT Contact_ID, First_Name_CH, Last_Name_CH, Contact_CD, Login_VC FROM [Worktool].[dbo].[vwEmployees_T] WHERE Login_VC = '" & username & "'"

        Using connection As New SqlConnection(cnn)
            Try
                If connection.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then connection.Open()
                adapter = New SqlDataAdapter(sql_query, connection)
                adapter.Fill(ds)
                User_ID = ds.Rows(0)("Contact_ID").ToString()
                User_First_Name = ds.Rows(0)("First_Name_CH").ToString()
                User_Last_Name = ds.Rows(0)("Last_Name_CH").ToString()
                User_Contact_CD = ds.Rows(0)("Contact_CD").ToString()
                User_Login = ds.Rows(0)("Login_VC").ToString()
                connection.Close()
            Catch ex As SqlException
                MsgBox("Sorry, there was an issue with the connection. Please try again ! ")
                Dim i As Integer
                For i = 0 To ex.Errors.Count - 1
                    errorMessages.Append("Index #" & i.ToString() & ControlChars.NewLine _
                        & "Message: " & ex.Errors(i).Message & ControlChars.NewLine _
                        & "LineNumber: " & ex.Errors(i).LineNumber & ControlChars.NewLine _
                        & "Source: " & ex.Errors(i).Source & ControlChars.NewLine _
                        & "Procedure: " & ex.Errors(i).Procedure & ControlChars.NewLine)
                Next i
                MsgBox(errorMessages.ToString())
            End Try
        End Using


    'Assign messages
        main_window_welcome.Text = "Welcome back, " & Replace(User_First_Name, " ", "") & " " & Replace(User_Last_Name, " ", "")
```

variable username is

```
Public username = Environ$("Username")
```

Comment: Have you researched persistent sessions in vb.net? What have you tried? You've made your SQL query and provided it, but it's not relevant to your problem.

Comment: @Litty I'm trying to access say User_ID anywhere else in my application. Any thoughts on how to go about that?

Comment: Sure. I'd say you Google "vb.net global variables" and [check out this result.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22738243/how-would-i-declare-a-global-variable-in-visual-basic) ;)

Comment: @Litty Yes, I've read that one multiple times.. I cannot figure out how to initialize the SQL Query, then assign that variable to a Public variable. That is my problem.

Comment: You said `I have an SQL query that returns user information` and that `This works well`. It sounds like you're trying to figure out how to store information in a global variable. The query has nothing to do with this.

Comment: @Litty the query has everything to do with this - I want User_ID which is populated from the SQL Query, to be a global variable. And to be able to access it in any form on my application.

Comment: You are concatenating strings inside of an append method of a stringbuilder which is counter productive as far as gaining the benefits of it's speed with concatenating strings for you - just saying!

Comment: @OneFineDay there are so many things to choose form in that code, how could you choose just the stringbuilder?

Comment: @OneFineDay I had referenced this code from another source, but it'd likely be removed for a more basic error message once application goes to production. I suppose looking at it, none of that is necessary and I could just include each error in the msgbox separately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've declared the 4 variables in the class and they are private to that class. At this point your code works. Hilight those 4 variable declarations and Cut them. Your code shows errors because you just removed the declarations.

Add a module to your solution (name it what you want)
paste the declarations into the module body.

change the Dim to Public.

Your errors disappear.

Your variables are now public and available throughout your solution.